# Cannot provision target computer for Windows driver testing, error code: 1312

Tags: windows, visual-studio, driver, wdk

I'm trying to follow the steps in this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-umdf-driver-based-on-a-template but during the provisioning part I keep getting an error.

I have completed most of the preparation steps outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/provision-a-target-computer-wdk-8-1.

The problem specifically occurs when provisioning through Visual Studio. I get Error code: 1312 Error message: Unable to create run session for specified user.
[image: error codes and message during provisioning]

I'm targeting a computer running Windows 10 Home and my host computer is running Windows 11 Home. Both are up to date and on the same network. If there's anything else I can provide to get some help with this please let me know.

I tried changing my firewall settings and the target computer's password settings/policy to see if the problem was with WDKRemoteUser being setup incorrectly but that didn't work.

One other thing that may be a problem is that during the preparation steps, I'm not sure what the result of running the WDK Test Target Setup MSI is supposed to be. When I run it, the installer window pops up and then disappears. I checked the list of supported devices and my NIC's are on there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/supported-ethernet-nics-for-network-kernel-debugging-in-windows-10

Also when checking if Secure Boot is enabled on my target PC it just says "unavailable" and in my BIOS the setting is the same so I'm assuming its not on?

Comment: 1312 = ERROR_NO_SUCH_LOGON_SESSION. See if there's a more detailed log file with more useful information. I've never used the deployment from visual studio as I've always found it unreliable. You can just copy the binaries and install them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Remove any changes you may have made to auto-login (DefaultPassword) in the registry (\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon).